# UiView added on multiple layers when used with addsubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am trying to add UIViews on the main view, the UIViews are circles (balls) which have an gravity animation.

[image]

The problem with this is that most of the time the views are added on different layers, like this,

[image]

Is there a way to add all those UIViews(Circles) on the main view, or on a single layer on it, as i need to add collision behavior on those circles.

**Edit:**

Here is my code for the UIView,

```html
    lblTimer = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameLabel];
    lblTimer.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lblTimer.text = @"0";
    
    //frameBall = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-12.5, touchPoint.y-12.5, 25, 25);
    frameBall = CGRectMake(xCoordinate-12.5, yCoordinate-12.5, 25, 25);
    viewBall = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameBall];
    viewBall.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5;
    viewBall.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    //CGRect frameLabel = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 25, 25);
    
    [viewBall addSubview:lblTimer];
    [self.view addSubview:viewBall];
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @GauravSrivastava - i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

## 1. one view = one layer

**but what you want** is all view layer to have the same parent layer, which they already do in the code above - it may look different because the simulator tries to show the items in a non-overlapping way.

---

if you really want X views to share a layer and not just a super-layer you are out of luck and just change your approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a view, it gets added to the top of the view hierarchy. This is due to the fact, that when two views collide, one of them has to be on top. The view hierarchy that you have captured is somewhat biased, because if you would have added the balls in a way that they do not overlap, I am pretty sure that they would look like they are on the same layer.

What you can do to add collision, is to try checking if the view that is moving, is inside another view subview:

```
for (UIView *anotherView in self.subviews) {
    if (movingView == anotherView)
        continue;
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(movingView.frame, anotherView.frame)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```